# Grep analog in Powershell

Tags: linux, windows, command-line, powershell

I'm trying to make a port for a project from linux to MS Server. The problem is that there is grep command with special options `grep -c string` and `grep -e` which I need to convert. Found that similar command in windows cmd is `FINDSTR` but I see now option similar to `-c` or `-e` options for `grep`. Any other solutions I've missed?

Comment: Install Unix tools such as `sh` and `grep` for Windows and use them?

Comment: Not in my case. The requirements are so that I cannot install that tools under Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Powershell's "select-string"
for -e regexp, it's -Pattern.
for -c count, there's no exact equivalent, u need to manipulate the output of select-string yourself. E.g., (select-string onefile -pattern "^[0-9].*").count

(sorry for the formatting; I m on a phone)

Comment: Can this be done by extending or creating custom powershell cmd? If it can, is there an example on making this kind of stuff? Thx

Comment: What is it for `sed`?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning you need to specify a particular usage with sed